# How to get timeout info from dataTask

Tags: ios, swift, api, url, timeout

I have the following code for requesting data from an external API:

```
var request = URLRequest(url: myURL!, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10.0)                 
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
let session = URLSession.shared
let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
    if error != nil {
        print(error)
    } else {
        let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
    }
})

dataTask.resume()
```

---

The `timeoutInterval` is set to `10.0`. But how can I get back info on *if* the request/session timed out, or how long the request/session took the complete? I will then use that info to determine which function I should call.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the error is not `nil` then cast error as `URLError` and check the `code` is `.timeout` or not. Here is the code.

```
var request = URLRequest(url: myURL!, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10.0)

request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

let session = URLSession.shared

let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    if (error != nil) {
        if let error = error as? URLError {
            if error.code == .timedOut {
                print("Timeout error")
            }
        }
        
        print(error)
    } else {
        let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
    }
})

dataTask.resume()
```

Comment: Thank you so much - that was exactly it!

Comment: the nil check is pointless.